# Exclude compile output files in intellij jar artifact

Tags: intellij-idea, jar

I am using intellij version 14. I want to exclude some files from the compile output before creating the jar artifact. I cannot mark them as excluded from the module sources since my code is accessing them using getClassLoader().getResource(). I don't want these files in the jar because they are huge in size and I would never be executing the jar such that the code that accesses these files runs.

What are some of the options to generate the jar output as an artifact from intellij by excluding these files?

Note - I understand that we could add pre-processing and post processing ant targets that could possibly help out here but what should I add in the ant target - delete the files from the compiled output folder as a pre-processing step?

Kindly let me know your thoughts. Thanks !

Comment: Any particular reason why you would have those files in the project if in the end they're not used? You could try excluding them when building the jar as suggested [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) and/or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707612/ant-jar-task-using-excludes-parameter)

Comment: They are needed in executing some programs that are not executed when the application is deployed as a jar.

Comment: Then perhaps they can be put in a separate dir (for convenience, or excluded individually) which will be excluded when building the jar as explained in those 2 links. Otherwise please share the build file or a [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: What are these files? Are they test resources? Reference documents? cat videos? Perhaps put them in a `src/test/resources` directory and mark them as test resources?

Comment: One reason you want to exclude some items is that IntellJ generates an .iml file in the compile output directory.  It servers some purpose, but you probably don't need in the jar artifact, but it's added to the jar artifact because you can't exclude it.  So this is a still a valid question, and the answer seems to be that you must live with such nuances that are outside of your control are not harmful.